# How much electron hybridization and bonding occurs in liquid helium?

Tags: bond, hybridization, liquids

Helium is the only element which does not freeze at atmospheric pressure, and only forms a liquid at around 4 Kelvin due to weak van der Waals forces.

I'm interested in knowing roughly how much hybridization/bonding occurs in liquid helium (e.g., energies in cm$^{-1}$ or electronvolts) at *ambient pressure and cryogenic temperatures*. I would guess that since the enthalpy of formation for liquid helium is about $10^{-3}$ eV per atom, the bonding energies are comparable, but I have not found any numbers on this topic in the literature.

To ask the same question without jargon: **how much are the energy levels of Helium smeared when it is in the liquid phase?**

For example, in solid Copper, a plot of the density of states shows that the atomic energy levels hybridize to form solid state energy bands. For the $d$-orbitals the overlaps are relatively small, giving rise to roughly 4eV wide bands. On the other hand the $s$- and $p$-orbitals have large overlaps, resulting in these atomic orbitals being broadened to be >12eV wide.

[image: DOI: 10.1088/0953-8984/21/34/345501]

Comment: "hybridization energy" sorry, but there is no such thing. Can you explain why you use this term?

Comment: I just mean the energy scale of the hybridization, sorry for not using the correct terms. For a single atom the levels are sharp lines, but in a liquid I assume those lines hybridize to form a band (like solids). What is the energy width of that band in liquid helium?

Comment: I have never heard the term "hybridisation" together with electronic band structures. And the electronic band structure has little to do with the dispersive attraction between atoms. *Metals* are kept together by their common electron gas. With a liquid isolator, I think this concept is a bit of a misapplication.

Comment: Ok, let me ask the same question without jargon: how much are the energy levels of Helium smeared when it is in the liquid phase?

Comment: To those who request closing the question due to lack of details, can you please elaborate? I am using terminology commonly used in the context of physics, but am learning that have slightly different connotations in chemistry. At the very least the bolded question should be well-defined.

Comment: @Karl I think your statement is not correct. You can get electron band structures even in insulating solids held together by "van der Waals forces". Hence you find that noble gases (besides Helium) can become solids with electronic band structures. I am using the term "hybridization" in the sense that atomic orbitals hybridize to form delocalized states in both metals and insulators, giving rise to electronic bands. See for example, https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.124.652

Comment: Are you interested in specific liquid phase conditions wrt temp and pressure? Here's a reference for high pressure and temp liquification: https://www.pnas.org/content/105/32/11071

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the reference. I have in mind liquid helium at cryogenic temperatures and atmospheric (or vacuum) pressure, like one would find in a laboratory. Let me add that to the question. I think the reference is focused on extremely large pressures and temperature (>10,000 Kelvin, >10Mbar)

Comment: Hybridization is a simplification, it doesn't do complicated.

Comment: I was guessing that you weren't interested in high P and T, but figured it was worth clarifying. My impression is that at standard P even at cryogenic temps, liquid helium has such low density that the atoms are not close enough together to have significant orbital overlap, but I don't know references off-hand to confirm that.